# Link in Chrome Extension sidepanel not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I had a email link in the side panel of my chrome extension. Both a link and a button worked:

```
<a href={"mailto:hi@email.com"}>Link</a>

<button 
  onClick={() => {
    window.location.href =
      "mailto:hi@email.com";
    }}
  >
  Button
</button>
```

However when I change `mailto:hi@email.com` to a url `"https://example.com/contact"` then it doesn't work. I dont have any errors in my console. In the network panel I can see Im getting a 304 but the size is 0 bytes.

Comment: You can't navigate sidePanel to a web URL, so add `target=_blank` attribute or use chrome.tabs.update({url: '....'})

Answer (score 1):

You may have a default app to handle email links, so when you try to open the `mailto` link, it just opens your default app (so it doesn't behave like a regular link being opened in your browser).

A Chrome extension is not able to open links in the same `sidePanel` frame it lives, so if you don't instruct your markup to open it elsewhere, Chrome will crash.

You just need to add `target="_blank"` attribute (with `rel="noreferrer"` for security reasons related to old browsers) to your `a` tags and they will work just fine (opening the links inside a new tab or a new window).